# Jquery 3.0.0 incompatible with Jquery Mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm just learning how to write Javascript. I've been told that this is how to include jquery and jquery mobile:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet"   
      href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
  <script src="scripts/jquery-3.0.0.min.js">
  </script>
  <script 
    src="scripts/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js">
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div data-role="page">
    <div data-role=header>My Page</div>
    <div data-role="content">
      <label for="entry">Enter a number:</label>
      <input type='number' name='entry' id='entry' min='0'>
      <button>My button</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The page above doesn't render mobile styles; it just looks like plain html. But if I change the jquery library to 2.2.4 (both are present in the scripts folder) it works and the text box and button look like a mobile app with no errors in the console. Is there some incompatibility here? Also, when I use 3.0.0 the console says: TypeError: a.event.props is undefined. I'm just curious as to what's going on here and why I have to use the older jquery.

Comment: JQM officially only supports JQuery up to 2.1.x `(jQuery 1.8 - 1.11 / 2.1)`  You may even run into problems if you're combining JQM with JQuery 2.2.x See the official site: https://jquerymobile.com/  - You can also find more information on the issue on their github page: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery 3 is all of [five days old](https://blog.jquery.com/2016/06/09/jquery-3-0-final-released/).  It also broke [some things](https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/).  [jQuery Migrate](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/), mentioned in both previous links, MIGHT make your setup work, but consider not blazing this trail.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. Thanks for clarifying this.

Comment: it's 2018 and still the same problem

Comment: yep, it is indeed

Comment: yep, it is indeed

Answer (score 9):

According to [this message](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/8546#issuecomment-271163317) on jquery-mobile github issue-tracker jquery-mobile version 1.5 should be compatible with jQuery 3.x.

It is not available at the main website at the moment, but is available at [code.jquery.com](http://code.jquery.com/mobile/)