# JQuery Mobile Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am trying to run one of the demos on jQuery Mobile. However, when I copy and paste the source code (though I replaced the links with Google CDNs) it doesn't work properly. In the console, it says: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'concat' of [here it says a few line numbers in jQuery Mobile] undefined". Here's my code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Ben Gubler</title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <div data-role="page" class="jqm-demos ui-responsive-panel" id="panel-responsive-page1" data-title="Panel responsive page" data-url="panel-responsive-page1">
      <div data-role="header">
          <h1>Panel responsive</h1>
          <a href="#nav-panel" data-icon="bars" data-iconpos="notext">Menu</a>
          <a href="#add-form" data-icon="gear" data-iconpos="notext">Add</a>
      </div><!-- /header -->
      <div role="main" class="ui-content jqm-content jqm-fullwidth">
          <h1>Panel responsive</h1>
          <p>This is a typical page that has two buttons in the header bar that open panels. The left panel has the push display mode, the right panel reveal. To make this responsive, you can make the page re-flow at wider widths. This allows both the panel menu and page to be used together when more space is available. This behavior is controlled by CSS media queries. You can create a custom one for a specific breakpoint or use the breakpoint preset by adding the <code>class="ui-responsive-panel"</code> to the page container. We have added this class on this demo page. Note that when using the preset class, we also hide the dismiss layer on wider screens if the panel has the push display mode.</p>
          <div data-demo-html="#panel-responsive-page1"></div><!--/demo-html -->
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <a href="../" data-rel="back" data-ajax="false" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-mini ui-btn-inline ui-icon-carat-l ui-btn-icon-left ui-alt-icon ui-nodisc-icon">Back</a>
      </div><!-- /content -->
      <div data-role="panel" data-display="push" data-theme="b" id="nav-panel">
          <ul data-role="listview">
              <li data-icon="delete"><a href="#" data-rel="close">Close menu</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#panel-responsive-page2">Accordion</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#panel-responsive-page2">Ajax Navigation</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#panel-responsive-page2">Autocomplete</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#panel-responsive-page2">Buttons</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#panel-responsive-page2">Checkboxes</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#panel-responsive-page2">Collapsibles</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#panel-responsive-page2">Controlgroup</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#panel-responsive-page2">Dialogs</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#panel-responsive-page2">Fixed toolbars</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#panel-responsive-page2">Flip switch toggle</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#panel-responsive-page2">Footer toolbar</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#panel-responsive-page2">Form elements</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#panel-responsive-page2">Grids</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#panel-responsive-page2">Header toolbar</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#panel-responsive-page2">Icons</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#panel-responsive-page2">Links</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#panel-responsive-page2">Listviews</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#panel-responsive-page2">Loader overlay</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#panel-responsive-page2">Navbar</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#panel-responsive-page2">Navbar, persistent</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#panel-responsive-page2">Pages</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#panel-responsive-page2">New</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#panel-responsive-page2">Popup</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#panel-responsive-page2">Radio buttons</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#panel-responsive-page2">Select</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#panel-responsive-page2">Slider, single</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#panel-responsive-page2">New</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#panel-responsive-page2">New</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#panel-responsive-page2">New</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#panel-responsive-page2">Text inputs & textarea</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#panel-responsive-page2">Transitions</a></li>
          </ul>
      </div><!-- /panel -->
      <div data-role="panel" data-position="right" data-display="reveal" data-theme="a" id="add-form">
          <form class="userform">
              <h2>Login</h2>
              <label for="name">Username:</label>
              <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" data-clear-btn="true" data-mini="true">
              <label for="password">Password:</label>
              <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" data-clear-btn="true" autocomplete="off" data-mini="true">
              <div class="ui-grid-a">
                  <div class="ui-block-a"><a href="#" data-rel="close" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-btn-b ui-mini">Cancel</a></div>
                  <div class="ui-block-b"><a href="#" data-rel="close" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-btn-a ui-mini">Save</a></div>
              </div>
          </form>
      </div><!-- /panel -->
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you very much! I believe the problem is in the linking... perhaps there is a problem with using the Google CDN? Earlier, when I downloaded the same source files that jQuery used for their website, it worked fine.

Comment: from the JQM home page: Latest stable: Version 1.4.5 compatible with jQuery 1.8 - 1.11 / 2.1 - see also here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44910517/4845566

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like jQuery Mobile might not be compatible with jQuery Core 3.  Page works when you downgrade to version `2.2.4`.

Use this instead of your first jQuery import.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

**More Info:**
[Jquery 3.0.0 incompatible with Jquery Mobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37821393/jquery-3-0-0-incompatible-with-jquery-mobile)

Answer (score 0):

If the answer above about 'not be compatible with jQuery Core 3' does not work, try to add the following to your style, it works for me:

```
@media (max-width: 1400px) {
  html, body {
    overflow: scroll;
  }
}
```