# How do I get jQuery mobile to work with app script?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, google-apps-script

I am attempting to construct a web app using google app script, google sheets, and jquery mobile.

My html is only displaying as unformatted text, and I am getting the following error message in my browser console:

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZFeE.png)

I notice in this post that their html code is that same as mine, at least I think it is:

[similar code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29922088/jquery-mobile-with-google-apps-script)

In their posted screenshots, it is clearly working, even though they had a separate issue with zoom level.

This is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.css">

<?!= include('JavaScript');?>
</head> 
<body> 

<div data-role="page" class="page" id="pgHome" data-title="My Page Title">

The rest of my html basically follows the boilerplate html from jquery.
```

This is my app script code:

```
function doGet() {
return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('myHtml').evaluate().setTitle("TAH Inventory Management");
}

function include(filename) {
return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(filename).evaluate().getContent();
}
```

My JavaScript.html file has scripts to populate a UL from google sheets.

Any idea why none of the structure or styling from jquery mobile is working?

I also attempted to use the snippet from jquery mobile itself, and that also did not work.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
```

I am very grateful for any help I can get on this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently my problem was incompatibility between jquery mobile and jquery 3, as explained in this post: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37821393/jquery-3-0-0-incompatible-with-jquery-mobile)

I changed my code to the following and it now works!

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.css">
```